# Subtracting one time string from another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that stores two different times:

```
Beginning  |   End
  17:05    |  17:10
```

I want to be able to get the difference between the two.

Right now, both columns are stored as strings. How can I convert them into a data type that is aggregate-friendly for time stamps?

Comment: Is that one column with two times, or two columns each with one time?

Comment: Its two columns with two with each having one time. 17:05 is 5:05pm etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` with the format `%H:%M`, then subtract the two:

```
df['Time_Difference'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%H:%M') - pd.to_datetime(df['Beginning'], format='%H:%M')

>>> df
  Beginning    End Time_Difference
0     17:05  17:10        00:05:00
```

Or if you actually want to change the `Beginning` and `End` columns, you can do something like:

```
df[['Beginning', 'End']] = df[['Beginning', 'End']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M'))
df['Time_Difference'] = df['End'] - df['Beginning']

>>> df
            Beginning                 End Time_Difference
0 1900-01-01 17:05:00 1900-01-01 17:10:00        00:05:00
```

But the default date will be added (`1900-01-01`)